# Create new column based on cut off date (date from another column)

Tags: r, date, dplyr, case

I have a sample df below (with date formatted into as.Date):

```
| date       |
--------------
| 2020-03-03 |
| 2020-06-30 |
| 2020-01-23 |
| 2020-02-10 |
| 2020-11-29 |
```

I am trying to add a column according to cut-off date of 2020-05-01 and expects to get this table:

```
| date       | cutoff |
------------------------
| 2020-03-03 | prior   |
| 2020-06-30 | later   |
| 2020-01-23 | prior   |
| 2020-02-10 | prior   |
| 2020-11-29 | later   |
```

I used dplyr and called the mutate to create a column and initially applied case_when:

```
df %>%
  mutate(cutoff = case_when(
    date < 2020-05-01 ~ "prior",
    "later"
  ))
```

The code above created cutoff column with only "later" values.

I also tried the ifelse:

```
df <- with(df, ifelse(date < 2020-05-01, "prior", "later"))
```

The code above replaced the values in the date column with NA value.

I gave a different code a try:

```
df %>%
  mutate(cutoff = case_when(date < 2020-05-01 ~ "prior", 
                          TRUE ~ "later"))
```

but the result was the same as the first code I tried.

I thought of converting the date into POSixct format, but each code above produced the same output as above.

Comment: Did you try wrapping `2020-05-01` in `as.Date()`?

Comment: I just tried, but the date is already in the proper date but it is still asking for the origin value. In this case, what should I supplement the origin date with?

Comment: Could you please post your sample dataframe into your question using `dput(df)`?

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing it right: Df <- data.frame(date = c(2020-03-03, 2020-06-30, 2020-01-23, 2020-02-10, 2020-11-29)), dput(Df). I tried it in the studio but this only showed incorrect years only. Apologies, not familiar with dput() yet

Comment: The dates should be wrapped in `"`. `dput()` returns a structure that can easily be imported and shows the _real_  structure of your data. Based on that possible solutions can be created. If possible, you should show part of the data you are using (as mentioned you did try some code on actual data). `dput(YourDataFrame)` or `dput(head(YourData))` should give the expected structure output.

Comment: Learned this from another help: df <- structure(list(date = c("2020-03-03", "2020-06-30", "2020-01-23", 
"2020-02-10", "2020-11-29")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define date class with `ymd` then use `ifelse`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date),
         cutoff = ifelse(date < ymd("2020-05-01"), "prior", "later"))
```

```
        date cutoff
1 2020-03-03  prior
2 2020-06-30  later
3 2020-01-23  prior
4 2020-02-10  prior
5 2020-11-29  later
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2020-03-03", "2020-06-30", "2020-01-23", 
"2020-02-10", "2020-11-29")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I may be missing something. I followed your format but it marked all dates as "prior" only. Let me give it another try later. My eyes may be tired from looking at the screen for several hours already. I will update you later. thanks

Comment: Check the class of date in your data, if it is class date then you don't need to transform it to class date as I did.  Check the code with the data I uploaded.

Comment: it worked. I oversaw my year in my actual df. Thanks